# 'check up on' vs 'check on', is there a difference?

Tags: phrase-usage, difference, phrasal-verbs

Entries for these phrasal verbs are almost identical in different dictionaries. Is there a difference in meaning or no? Is there a nuance that users should be mindful of?

Check on sb/sth: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/check-on-sb-sth?q=check%2Bon%2Bsb%252Fsth

check up on sb/sth:https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/check-up-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are slightly different in meaning. `check on up` refers to something more precise and a situation that needs more attention. `You check up on a sick baby` but `you check on a sleeping baby`.

Check up on sb also means:

> to see if someone is doing what he/she is supposed to be doing